# Refusal of Schengen visa (Netherlands short stay French embassy)

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

How can we appeal successfully after refusal? We have 2 refusals from the same French embassy. The only reason for refusal was, "Not sure the applicant will leave the country on time."

Comment: Provide sufficient proof to the embassy to convince them that you don't intend to overstay than the expected period of time. Also, why are you applying for a visa to the Netherlands at the French Embassy? Apply either at the embassy of the longest stay or the first entry.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Schengen countries have agreements to represent each other for visa purposes in specific countries. If the French embassy/consulate was not the right one, it would not refuse the visa but decline to process the application.

Comment: @Relaxed Just because you can does not mean you should.

Comment: @fkraiem In that case it does. There is in any case only one consulate competent to examine applications from a certain area and it might very well be one from another Schengen country, depending on agreements.

Comment: @fkraiem France handles visa applications for the Netherlands in Chad, Central Africa, Congo, Gabon, Jamaica, etc. [See the list](http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/visa/documenten-en-publicaties/publicaties/2014/02/20/ambassades-verantwoordelijk-voor-visum-kort-verblijf.html)

Comment: @Relaxed I understand what you mean, I was not aware of this earlier and the question seemed ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should try to show you have strong ties with your country of residence, things that would compel you to come back and make an illegal stay in the Netherlands less attractive. A good situation/job, family, a house, etc. could all go some way toward that but at this stage it might not be enough. Consulates have a large “margin of appreciation”, especially for this reason.

In practice, you should submit any document that would establish that and could also write a letter articulating your arguments (your wish to come back to your country, etc.).

Comment: I think you could provide more information regarding how one can show such strong ties and all. For instance bank statements or company records etc.